# Pose Graph SLAM Frontend and Backend confusion

Tags: slam, localization, pose, optimization, graph

I have confusion about constructing the graph for pose graph SLAM. What I understood, there are two types of edges (i.e. constraints):

1. Edge/Constraint between two consecutive poses
2. Edge/Constraint between two non-consecutive poses (also called Loop Closure)

Let's say I start from position (x0,y0). If I move somewhat, my next consecutive position will be (x1,y1). Those positions are described by nodes. So I will have node N0 and N1. Let's also say I have node N7. N1 and N7 are non-consecutive nodes. So to summarize, I want to examine in following discussion two scenarions, where I have:

3. Two consecutive nodes N0,N1
4. Two non-consecutive nodes N1,N7

Let's first examine situation with two consecutive nodes N0,N1. I need to know relative transformation between these two nodes. I can get that transformation by using:

5. Wheel odometry (i.e. ${N_1}^{-1} \cdot N_0$)
6. LiDAR Scan Matching (will give some transformation)

Let's now examine situation with two non-consecutive nodes N1,N7. I need to know relative transformation between these two nodes. I can get that transformation by using:

7. What graph tells me (i.e. ${N_7}^{-1} \cdot N_1$)
8. LiDAR Scan Matching (will give some transformation)

So, my first question is, is my understanding so far good? For each two nodes, whether they are consecutive or non-consecutive we can get two transformations from two different sources (in our case with wheel odometry and lidar setup)?

When it comes to pose graph optimization (backend SLAM) we have to optimize now. We want to minimize function $F(x) = \sum e_{ij} * \Omega_{ij} \cdot e_{ij}$, for each constraint $e_{ij}$, where $e_{ij} = z_{ij} - q_{ij}$. Where $z_{ij}$ is **real measurement** (number 8 in list above) and $q_{ij}$ is **virtual measurement** (i.e. what current configuration of graph gives is - number 7 in list above).

This is intuitive for me for non-consecutive nodes, **but what about consecutive nodes**? Is the thing the same? $q_{ij}$ will be expected measurement (from odometry i.e. what current configuration of graph gives us), $z_{ij}$ will be real measurement (transformation from some ICP between two scans of those two nodes)?

So basically for every two nodes, whether they are **consecutive** or **non-consecutive**, we would need to have two constraints, one that is relative transformation between two nodes based on current graph (bullets 5 and 7), and another that is relative transformation between two nodes based on some LiDAR measurements (bullets 6 and 8)? And then we would be able to define error function $e_{ij}$ and proceed with minimizing sum of squared error loss function?

This is what I understood from this paper:
[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 3]

This is image describing that:
[image: Image 2]

Thank you very much in advance!